# Finding the next element in an unordered array

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an unordered array of which I can not sort. Not because I can't, because its order is critical to the application. Not knowing the index of the element I currently have, how do I find the element following it?

What I have devised thus far:

```
/**
* @return int - the ID || -1 for out of bounds
*/
public function getNextID(currentID:int):int{
    var found:Boolean = false;
    for each(var id:int in mIDs){
        if(found){
            return id;
        }
        if(id == currentID){
            found = true;
        }
    }return -1;
}
```

I am merely asking this because I am seeking a better solution that possibly doesn't call for a loop and am interested in educating myself better on the options available in AS3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function getNextID(currentID:int):int {
    var index:int = mIDs.indexOf(currentID);
    if (index == -1 || index + 1 >= mIDs.length) return -1;
    return mIDs[index + 1];
}
```

The [`indexOf`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#indexOf%28%29) function gets first index in the array that corresponds to the search parameter. If it doesn't exist, it returns -1. We can use that in conjunction with array index accessor syntax (using brackets `[]`) to easily find the right value.